# Expandible and Collapsible Columns in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using a Gridview in asp.net. Columns are in this fashion : Apr,May,Jun,Q1,July,Aug,Sep,Q2,Oct,Nov,Dec,Q3,Jan,Feb,Mar,Q4.
I want to display the gridview as below :

1. Initially only columns Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 should be visible.
2. If I click on Q1, Apr,May,Jun columns should be visible. Q2,Q3,Q4 are still visible.
3. If I click on Q2, Oct,Nov,Dec columns should be visible. Q1,Q3,Q4 are still visible.
4. If I click on Q3, Oct,Nov,Dec columns should be visible. Q1,Q2,Q4 are still visible.
5. If I click on Q4, Jan,Feb,Mar columns should be visible. Q1,Q2,Q3 are still visible.

Clicking again on any expanded column should collapse it as it was before

Anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Apply a CssClass to each of the columns that is represented. It doesn't have to be a functioning css element, just a name.

```
<asp:BoundField ID="Apr" CssClass="Q1" .... />
```

Then you can use a header template for the Q1 column that includes a link. The link's click event should call a jQuery that calls a method to toggle `hide()` and `show()` for elements in matching the class. Here would be a function idea:

```
function ToggleColumn(colID)
{
    var elements = $('.' + col);
    if (elements[0].is(":visible"))
    {
        elements.hide();
    } else {
        elements.show();
    }

    return false;
}
```

And the link to call it would be:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkQ1" OnClientClick="return ToggleColumn('Q1');" ... />
```

This will obviously need tweaking to get right against your specific requirements, and there will need to be some null checks put into place where failures could occur. If you treat this as pseudo-code it should get you headed in the right direction.